# record audio data while using speech recognition?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, recording

I'm successfully using the .NET speech recognition portion in my C# application for basic talking things.

In addition to this, is it possible to record the audio that it picks up inside my application in parallel with my application recognizing it.  I want to save it for a later date so I can analyze it.

Would you create a separate thread and then put some .NET audio recordings in there when I speak into the microphone?  I only want to save them in a local directory, in .wav format.  An easy recording such as 48khz and 16 bit sample.

I'm using a normal form application, and this is the type of speech code I have now just to give you an idea.

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;

//then inside the class and namespace I have 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();


//declared variables here
//now I initialize

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"Commands.txt")))));
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            systemOnline();
        }

void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string time = now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
            int ranNum;
            string speech = e.Result.Text;
            switch (speech)
            {

                //Open Google
                case "Google":
                //code opens google in default browser
```

Comment: it looks like it already saves it in memory, so all you would have to do is have it send the memory location to file before it releases that recording from the application.  I think.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Windows APIs. I am sure you can register an handler/event handler/interceptor there, to get the audio data. Check out following link: [maybe helpfull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The second one in your link I'll look into more.  It appears I can use it as a shared event.  Thanks :)

Comment: not sure, threading is not my superior area, you have to look at your CPU and the features on it, if it is a multicore and supports multiple audio data/stream calculations on each core, then threading will be helpful!